# how to retrieve plot keywords for specific movie id using imdbpy from imdb

Tags: python, information-retrieval, imdb, imdbpy

i want to retrieve plot keywords for specific movie id using IMDBPY  from IMDb  .any idea? i just know that

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()

# get a movie and print its name
the_matrix = ia.get_movie('0133094')
print(the_matrix)
```

Comment: What do you mean by plot keyword?

Comment: see this please[link] (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3553976/keywords?ref_=tttg_sa_3)

Comment: `plot = ia.get_keyword('plot', results=5)` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: where do i Add movie Id?

Comment: What you want to do? You want to get the keywords of a movie? Or You want to search all movies with plot keyword?

Comment: i want to give it  movie id  and it returns plot keywords .

Comment: i want to get the keyword of a movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter that's `info='keywords'` to get the keywords of a movie.

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
black_panther = ia.get_movie('1825683', info='keywords')
print(black_panther['keywords'])
```

Comment: it return error for movies that don't have plot keyword like this movie-id '5950092'

Comment: Now what can I do in that case? It's the problem with their API, You can use exception handling to handle the exceptions.